# JNDI initial context for JtaTransactionManager using Spring and Glassfish

Tags: java, spring, glassfish, jndi, jta

I want to use JTA Transaction Manager for my application. I'm using Spring and Glassfish. I want to use JNDI lookup to get the `JtaTransactionManager` instance. My Spring bean configuration for `JtaTransactionManager` is set up as follows:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="jtaTransactionManager"/>

<bean id="jtaTransactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager">
    <property name="transactionManagerName" value="java:comp/TransactionManager"/>
    <property name="userTransactionName" value="java:comp/UserTransaction"/>
</bean>
```

But when I run the program, it reported errors:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: JTA UserTransaction is not available at JNDI location [java:comp/UserTransaction]; nested exception is javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
```

which is associated with Non-initialized JNDI context. So I added a resource file `jndi.properties` which adds the missing initial context reported above:

```
java.naming.factory.initial=???
```

But the question is: What should I put in the above JNDI initial context field to be able get Glassfish transaction manager via JNDI lookup? I searched a number of sources but didn't find this piece of information. The [official document](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1752/gaxit/index.html) only says:

> To access a UserTransaction instance, you can either look it up using
>   the java:comp/UserTransaction JNDI name or inject it using the
>   @Resource annotation.

So how should I set up the JNDI initial factory for JTA Transaction Manager in `jndi.properties` file so that both `TransactionManager` and `UserTransaction` can be injected into my `jtaTransactionManager` bean by JNDI lookup? Thanks.

Comment: Instead of using the `JtaTransactionManager` use `<tx:jta-transaction-manager />` that does detection on which server you are running and does some environment specific lookups and configuration.

Comment: @M.Deinum I tried this but doesn't work. It says `No JTA UserTransaction available - specify either 'userTransaction' or 'userTransactionName' or 'transactionManager' or 'transactionManagerName'`.

Comment: If you are running the application on/in glassfish it should work, it is what we use here in production for a couple of applications. Which glassfish and spring version are you using?

Comment: Glassfish version is 3.1 and Spring version is 3.2. So I don't need to specify the JNDI initial context in `jndi.properties` file in order to detect the transaction manager?

Comment: Never added that file only `<tx:jta-transaction-manager />` when using a local transactionmanager. If you are using a remote JNDI you will have to add that file. But I assume you are deploying on the same glassfish as you want to use for transactions.

Comment: Yes I'm deploying it on the same server.